# Servico de autenticação de usuario para aplicativos desktop?

Tags: delphi, autenticação

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo para desktop em delphi, mas não pretendo construir a parte que controla acesso de usuários por não conhecer muito bem esta parte e tempo limitado. gostaria de usar um serviço online para tal tarefa. Alguém conhece um serviço como este ?

Comment: Talvez o serviço mais famoso atualmente seja o login do Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login?locale=pt_BR. Ou seja, o usuário entraria na sua aplicação colocando login/senha dele no Facebook. Mas não tenho dúvida que criar uma integração desta na sua aplicação é tão, senão até mais, difícil e demorada que construir sua própria camada de controle de acesso.

Comment: Se o sistema é para desktop, utilize um componente desktop, nativo do delphi, existem varios, um muito bom e 'di gratis', muito utilizado no Brasil é o [Usercontrol.](https://github.com/infussolucoes/usercontrol-sd) Veja  [a descrição dos componentes aqui.](http://showdelphi.com.br/descricao-dos-componentes-usercontrol/)

Answer (score 1):

Existem serviços pagos como o Stormpath (https://stormpath.com) ou você pode utilizar oauth2 para fazer o chamado "social login" onde os usuários podem utilizar as contas de suas redes sociais como Facebook, twitter além do github, Google.

Faça uma análise cuidadosa dessa necessidade antes de implementá-la pois no final das contas pode ser mais trabalhoso do que criar a sua própria. Se for só para autenticaçāo de usuários o oauth2 talvez seja interessante, mas se somado a isso você precisar efetuar controle de acesso aos módulos do sistema, permissōes e etc ele não vai te ajudar.

Comment: Ele afirma que o app é desktop, em delphi, então não me parece que sua resposta se aplica ao contexto dele.

Comment: Mas me parece que ele mencionou "Serviço" e acredito que nāo exista serviço offline, correto? Agora se ele quis dizer "componente" ai ele precisa melhorar o contexto dele.

Comment: Verdade, mas é, no mínimo, estranho autenticar usuarios de app desktop através de serviços online, mesmo pq app desktops nem sempre podem estar o tempo todo online, talvez ele tenha as 'bolas misturado', ou, como diria caetano e/ou gil, "ou não". :-)

Comment: Sim, se app dele for standalone e offline nao tem muito o que fazer senao implementar o proprio modulo.

Comment: O aplicativo é desktop, online e sera necessário somente autenticação de usuário mesmo.

Comment: Então nesse caso a resposta do @GyowannyPessattoQueiroz está correta.